# Wiring implementations in Spring MVC using @Autowired annotation

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, implementation

**What is the correct way to wire components in Spring?** Right now I have two classes that implement an interface, and if I @Autowire the interface in two implementation-classes, Spring gets confused about which of the implementation-class it should use. So first I tried to use a @Component("name") annotation in the two different implementations to give them different names (if I understand this correctly), but it still failed.

What I ended up doing in the end was declaring the specific Dao implementations (I have multiple Dao implementations) in the Service classes, since I got an error saying I had two implementations, and it was expecting only one. (**NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2**)

**Code involved in the question (please request more if it helps)**

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="studyeasy"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
          <property name="prefix">
              <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
           </property>
          <property name="suffix">
             <value>.jsp</value>
          </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- datasource bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="***" />
        <property name="username" value="***" />
        <property name="password" value="***" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

DatabaseDao.java:

```
package studyeasy.dao;

import ...;

public interface DatabaseDao {
    public void insertObject(Object obj);
    public List<Object> getObjectList();
    public void updateObject(Object obj);
    public void deleteObject(String id);
    public Object getObject(String id);
}
```

PersonDaoImpl.java:

```
package studyeasy.dao;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import ...;

@Repository
public class PersonDaoImpl implements DatabaseDao {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void insertObject(Object obj) {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

UtilityDaoImpl.java:

```
package studyeasy.dao;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import ...;

@Repository
public class UtilityDaoImpl implements DatabaseDao {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void insertObject(Object obj) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

DatabaseService.java:

```
package studyeasy.services;

import ...;

public interface DatabaseService {
    public void insertObject(Object object);
    public List<Object> getObjectList();
    public void deleteObject(String id);
    public Object getObject(String id);
    public void updateObject(Object object);
}
```

PersonServiceImpl.java:

```
package studyeasy.services;

import studyeasy.dao.PersonDaoImpl;
import ...;

@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements DatabaseService {

    @Autowired
    PersonDaoImpl personDao;

    @Override
    public void insertObject(Object object) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

UtilityServiceImpl.java:

```
package studyeasy.services;

import studyeasy.dao.UtilityDaoImpl;
import ...;

@Service
public class UtilityServiceImpl implements DatabaseService {

    @Autowired
    UtilityDaoImpl utilityDao;

    @Override
    public void insertObject(Object obj) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

**Any suggestions?**

**EDIT:**

After adding @Qualifier's to both ServiceImpl-classes, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [studyeasy.dao.DatabaseDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=personDao)}
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Name your beans and use the org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier annotation to define which bean to wire by its name

example:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("someDataSource")
DataSource dataSource;
```

Comment: So after adding a Qualifier to all my classes (do I need to add a Qualifier to each class?), I can declare the interface of the DAO-implementation-classes in the service-classes?

Like  
`@Autowired
@Qualifier("utilityDao")
DatabaseDao databaseDao;`

Comment: In the @Qualifier annotation you define the name of the bean you want to wire.
The bean name is specified in the bean definition.
ex:
@Component("mybeanName")
public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean{
(...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Qualifier` to distinguish which candidate bean to use:

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("fooBean") MyBean bean;
```

Note that constructor injection is far preferable to field injection, and if you use Java configuration, you can just call your constructor with the appropriate implementation.

(As a final note: If you use Spring Data, you can probably skip implementing DAOs entirely and have them autogenerated for you.)

Comment: So after adding a Qualifier to all my classes (do I need to add a Qualifier to each class?), I can declare the interface of the DAO-implementation-classes in the service-classes? Like `@Autowired @Qualifier("utilityDao") DatabaseDao databaseDao;`

Comment: @LifeOfAStudent You only need to add the qualifier to the item you're trying to wire. That said, though, your use case seems like you're trying really hard to avoid a good API design (one that is *at least* generic in this case).

Comment: @LifeOfAStudent You need to supply the correct name. If you don't specify one, it'll be `personServiceImpl`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use @qualifier, check this link:
https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier